# SessionStorage setting variable boolean as NaN or null (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, session-storage

when i set an item in session storage, (then refresh the page) and then set a variable as the item, for some reason it sets that variable as either NaN or null, how can i stop this? (save files)

```
    var myVar = false;

function save() {
    sessionStorage.setItem("myVar", myVar)
}

function load(){
    myVar = sessionStorage.getItem("myVar")
    myVar = parseInt(myVar) //is supposed to set myVar as the stored variable called "myVar"
    //if i do console.log() and print the variable value, it either shows up as NaN or Null
    //if i didnt do 'parseInt' then the value will be 'false', but the value is in strings???
    //(when value is in strings, it wont work in an "if (myVar == false){}")
}
```

Comment: `parseInt(false)` results in `NaN`. Why are you doing this? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @evolutionxbox, shouldnt it be obvious? save files.

Comment: @evolutionxbox why else would i want to store a variable in session storage? if im not planning on using it later??

Comment: What files? This is the first time you've mentioned files at all. What makes that obvious? --- Besides that, I'm not asking why are you saving variables in localStorage, I'm asking why you're trying to parse `undefined` to an int?

Comment: it prints `NaN` because it is `boolean` not a number that you parse between `parseInt()`

Comment: if you want to parse a boolean, use this:
`myVar = (myVar=="true")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Values stored in `sessionStorage` are strings.

Use this to convert to boolean :

`myVar = sessionStorage.getItem("myVar") === "true";`

Comment: *because values stored in local/session storage are strings.

Comment: thank you @Tom, your a life saverr!!!